# Scheduling emails with data from MySQL database or text file

Tags: php, mysql, email, cron, scheduling

I am creating a service where users submit data that is stored in a MySQL database or text file and emailed to a specific address at a certain time each week.

I understand that this is not what PHP is for and I've read of something called Cron that does the job, but I was wondering if there are any other options? Is there a script that could send from Gmail perhaps with the data pasted or attached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only think in two ways to do it:

1. Having a cron job to call your send script every x minutes

   ```
   $database->query("SELECT * FROM `mail_queue` WHERE `time` < " . time());
   while($object = $res->fetch_object()){
       mail($object->to, $object->subject, $object->message, "FROM: xpto@domain.com");
   }
   ```

   (If you're using a webhosting account you can simply create it on the control panel)

   ```
   * * * * * /bin/php complete_path_to_your_php_script.php
   ```
2. Having a script running in a loop (not reliable as it can stop working due to a timeout, error, memory outage, ...)

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use Cron jobs. If for some reasons you are not able to use them then you can use services of [thecloudblocks.com](http://www.thecloudblocks.com/) which allows you to schedulejobs.

Alternatively, you can create a function to sleep untill the time for the job comes. Like,

```
function do_some_job_at($time){
       time_sleep_until($time);
       JOB();
}

do_some_job_at(time() + 20); //Runs job after 20 seconds.
```

Comment: Yah, another option if for some reason you don't have cron access - http://webcron.org/

Answer (score 0):

If you need the php script to be running at all times then I would suggest using upstart jobs / services